# Rails: ActiveResource - Can I set the ID explicitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activeresource

I am using ActiveResource in Rails to manage entities in a separate database over REST.

I have been trying to explicitly manage the IDs of the remote resources, as for the current case it is simplest to just re-use the local resource's ID, rather than maintain a different field.

Unfortunately I have not been able to get this working as the code for `new?` in `ActiveResource::Base` is

```
  def new?
    id.nil?
  end
```

and `save` is

```
 def save
   new? ? create : update
 end
```

So from that by definition it is impossible to set an ID of a resource and save it as a new resource.

`create` and `update` are protected methods, so if I hacked the ActiveResource::Base code perhaps that would make it work, but I am loath to do that.

Is there a correct way of doing this? Or is what I am trying to do just bad, and I shouldn't do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working against the intentions of ActiveResource. ActiveResource provides an interface to REST webservices, which by convention return the assigned ID when you do a create.

That said, if you control the resource you're using, and you have modified its behavior to take an ID when saving a new record, you could modify ActiveResource::Base to conform. It's really not uncommon for folks in Rails to make additions and changes to base classes; you just put your patch in lib and include it somewhere in your startup stuff.

I don't think it's a good idea, necessarily, but it is possible. :)

Answer (score 4):

In new rails (tested 2.3.2) id can be set, as saving logic has changed a bit (now records have boolean field @newrecord to eliminate that id.nil?).

```
record = Model.new
record.id = 123
record.save!
```

Comment: Just to clarify - is that in ActiveResource or ActiveRecord? (any link for reference?)

Comment: Oops, misread a bit, sorry - above is correct for ActiveRecord. For resource case it's better to rename the ID field for the comunication thus no need for changing rails.

Comment: Or you can simply alter remote controller update action to actually do a "create_or_update"